# (Lift) Ajax submit using SHtml.select onchange event

Tags: scala, lift

I'm tring to implement the classic functionality of this select:elements depends on this other select:selection using Lift, E.g. select the country and get the possible states for the selected country.

The problem that I'm facing is that the "this.myForm.submit()" that I have inside the onchange of the select element is not firing the ajax request. If I use an input type"submit" it works perfectly.

Is this behaivior related with Lift framework? Is there a better way of implementing this kind of functionality using Lift libraries?

The relevant snipped code:

```
"name=distributionPoints" #> SHtml.select(distributionPoints, Empty, selectedDistributionPoint = _, "id" -> "the_distributionPoints") &
        "name=devices" #> (SHtml.select(devices, Empty, selectedDevice = _, "id" -> "the_devices")  ++ SHtml.hidden(process))
```

The view html:

```
<form class="lift:form.ajax">
<select name="distributionPoints" id="the_distributionPoints" onchange="submit()">
                    <option></option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                Device:
                <select name="devices" id="the_devices">
                    <option></option>
                </select>
</form>
```

The rendered HTML:

```
    <form id="F391649920812YBACEZ" action="javascript://" onsubmit="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler(jQuery('#'+&quot;F391649920812YBACEZ&quot;).serialize(), null, null, &quot;javascript&quot;);return false;">
                <div>  
Punto de distribución:
                <select onchange="submit()" id="the_distributionPoints" name="F630704816482OLP514"></select>
                <br />              
                    Equipo:
                    <select name="F391649920817BLRJW5" id="the_devices"></select><input type="hidden" name="F391649920818HPS35E" value="true" />
                    <br />

                </div>
            </form>
```

[edit]

I finally got the solution. Like Chris mentioned I used ajaxSelect instead of just selects and instead of using setHtml there's a method called JsCmds.ReplaceOptions that does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that when using Ajax submit the page is not reloaded. So I would suggest you to use `JsCmds.setHtml` on server side to "reset" the second select element.

So, in fact the first select is an ajaxSelect which is meant to modify the second one (so it is not concerned by the hidden submit in my opinion). The second select is updated when the first one is changed, using 'selectPoint(s)'

**Piece of Scala code**

```
def selectPoint(s):JsCmd = {
  selectedDistributionPoint = s; 
  newDevices:List[String] = findCorrespondingDevices(s);
  JsCmds.setHtml("name=devices", SHtml.select(newDevices, Empty, selectedDevice = _, "id" -> "the_devices")) ++ SHtml.hidden(process)) 
}

"name=distributionPoints" #> SHtml.AjaxSelect(distributionPoints, Empty, s=> selectPoint(s), "id" -> "the_distributionPoints") &
"name=devices" #> (SHtml.select(Nil, Empty, selectedDevice = _, "id" -> "the_devices")  ++ SHtml.hidden(process))
```

**Piece of template code**

```
<input name="distributionPoints" id="the_distributionPoints" onchange="submit()"/>
<input name="devices" id="the_devices"/>
```

Comment: I would apreciate a wider explanation. But what I understand is that you recommend me is to reset the whole page instead just reset the single select component. But the problem that I'm facing is that I just can't notify the server that the ajax operation must be done because I cant submit the form using onchange event.

Comment: I will post a solution as soon as I access my computer (tablets are not ideal). But setHtml sets a piece of the page (like a for example) so it won't refresh the whole page.

Comment: Hi Chris,that solution is exactly what I was looking for. I'm almost there, the "selectPoint" function is executed correctly when the main selector changes, but the second selector never changes. The response of the ajax call looks just fine try{jQuery("#name=distributionCenters").each(function(i) {this.innerHTML = "<select name=\"F4303480477262IHLNR\" id=\"the_devices\"><option value=\"device1\">device1</option></select><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"F430348047727OVLQCX\" value=\"true\" />";});} catch (e) {} Any idea? Everything points to the JsCMds.setHTML but can't say for sure.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem but I still do not know how to solve it. It looks like instead of replacing the select with name "devices" the setHtml is appending as child a new selector. Firebug output: <select id="the_devices" name="F1051456711131SZUCNQ">
<select id="the_devices" name="F1051456711140IYZQI2">
<option value="device1">Device 1</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="F1051456711141ROCUJC" value="true"/>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="F1051456711132KBLNOD" value="true"/>

Comment: Ok, I finally solve it. Instead of using setHtml I used ReplaceOptions. I ended with more questions than answers :p First of all, why I can't use selectors in setHtml and ReplaceOptions, it looks like using the element id is mandatory. Next, why setHtml does not replace the element? If thats the normal behavior, David should used appendChild. Finally, damm! Whats wrong with Lift documentation and literature. All books I have read never go deep in more complex concepts and the best source of information I have found "simplylift" is still incomplete and outdated.

Comment: I'm glad it works! You should post your solution in order to have a totally working one. For setHtml, I use it and it replaces elements, but maybe the identifier is not well used (usually I work with a div). For documentation, this is the main problem of Lift. The community says that everything is on the mailing List. Which is nearly true but the lack of doc makes it really hard to learn the language. That's why I would prefer stackoverflow usage and also some good books and a well commented documentation and code.